# Injecting dependency into entity repository

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Is there a simple way to inject a dependency into every repository instance in Doctrine2 ?

I have tried listening to the `loadClassMetadata` event and using setter injection on the repository but this naturally resulted in a infinite loop as calling `getRepository` in the event triggered the same event.

After taking a look at the `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::getRepository` method it seems like repositories are not using dependency injection at all, instead they are instantiated at the function level:

```
public function getRepository($entityName)
{
    $entityName = ltrim($entityName, '\\');
    if (isset($this->repositories[$entityName])) {
        return $this->repositories[$entityName];
    }

    $metadata = $this->getClassMetadata($entityName);
    $customRepositoryClassName = $metadata->customRepositoryClassName;

    if ($customRepositoryClassName !== null) {
        $repository = new $customRepositoryClassName($this, $metadata);
    } else {
        $repository = new EntityRepository($this, $metadata);
    }

    $this->repositories[$entityName] = $repository;

    return $repository;
}
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use a custom EntityManager you could override the `getRepository` method. Since this doesn't involve the `loadClassMetadata` event, you won't run into an infinite loop.

You would first have to pass the dependency to your custom EntityManager, and then you'd pass it to the repository object using setter injection.

I answered how to use a custom EntityManager [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138962/is-there-a-way-to-specify-doctrine2-entitymanager-implementation-class-in-symfon/8140007#8140007), but I'll replicate the answer below:

1 - Override the `doctrine.orm.entity_manager.class` parameter to point to your custom entity manager (which should extend `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager`.)

2 - Your custom entity manager must override the `create` method so that it returns an instance of your class. See my example below, and note the last line regarding `MyEntityManager`:

```
public static function create($conn, Configuration $config, EventManager $eventManager = null) {
        if (!$config->getMetadataDriverImpl()) {
            throw ORMException::missingMappingDriverImpl();
        }

        if (is_array($conn)) {
            $conn = \Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getConnection($conn, $config, ($eventManager ? : new EventManager()));
        } else if ($conn instanceof Connection) {
            if ($eventManager !== null && $conn->getEventManager() !== $eventManager) {
                throw ORMException::mismatchedEventManager();
            }
        } else {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Invalid argument: " . $conn);
        }

        // This is where you return an instance of your custom class!
        return new MyEntityManager($conn, $config, $conn->getEventManager());
    }
```

You'll also need to `use` the following in your class:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Configuration;
use Doctrine\ORM\ORMException;
use Doctrine\Common\EventManager;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;
```

**Edit**

Since the default entity manager is created from the `create` method, you can't simply inject a service into it. But since you're making a custom entity manager, you can wire it up to the service container and inject whatever dependencies you need.

Then from within the overridden `getRepository` method you could do something like
`$repository->setFoo($this->foo)`. That's a very simple example - you may want to first check if `$repository` has a `setFoo` method before calling it. The implementation is up to you, but this shows how to use setter injection for a repository.

Comment: How can I modify the doctrine.orm.entity_manager.class service to add the setter injection ? I've looked at the definition at `vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/DoctrineBundle/Resources/config/orm.xml` but i'm somewhat confused at how to add the injection as i'm using yml for my services definitions

Comment: I got everything setup correctly but i'm stuck at the part when you are saying "you can wire it up to the service container and inject whatever dependencies you need" I have a setContainer method on my custom EntityManager and I don't know what configuration to use to "wire it".

Comment: I'm also confused about that last "wire it up to the service container" step.

Comment: I too am unsure how to "wire it up to the service container" - everything else looks great! Any further advice?

Comment: Is it possible to inject custom parameters/configuration into this custom Manager? (I posted the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20757571/inject-additional-configuration-into-custom-entity-document-manager)). I think I also have a problem to undersand how to "wire it up to the service container".

Comment: Doctrine is a separate library, and is not Symfony specific. It would be much better to wrap calls to Doctrine repositories in a service. You would then be able to inject any needed dependencies into the service. A repository class should only be responsible for fetching data from an entity, or a group of entities. If you need to do other things in addition to fetching data, you should do those in a service.

Answer (score 35):

Problem is that repository classes are not part of the Symfony2 codebase as they are part of Doctrine2, so they do not take advantage of the DIC; this is why you can't go for injection in one place for all repositories.

I would advice you to use a different approach. For example you can create a service layer on top of the repositories and actually inject the class you want through a factory in that layer.

Otherwise you could also define repositories as services this way:

```
<service id="your_namespace.repository.repos_name"
          class="%your_namespace.repository.repos_name%"
          factory-service="doctrine" factory-method="getRepository">
  <argument>entity_name</argument>
  <argument>entity_manager_name</argument>
  <call method="yourSetter">
      <argument>your_argument</argument>
  </call>
</service>
```

A solution that could centralize the set method call is to write a DIC tag and a compiler pass to handle it and tag all repository services.

Comment: Upvoted for great answer but I have opted for Arms answer because I find it easier to implement.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer. I was relying on a mildly hacky method that stopped working in version 2.3. I switched to this method and it works great. I posted a YAML format of the same below just for reference.

Answer (score 16):

This is a YAML version of Aldo's answer, just in case you are using YAML configurations instead of XML

```yaml
your_namespace.repository.repos_name:
    class: %your_namespace.repository.repos_name%
    factory: ["@doctrine", getRepository]
    arguments:
        - entity_name
        - entity_manager_name
    calls:
        - [setContainer, ["@service_container"]]
```

And prior to version 2.8:

```yaml
your_namespace.repository.repos_name:
    class: %your_namespace.repository.repos_name%
    factory_service: doctrine
    factory_method: getRepository
    arguments:
        - entity_name
        - entity_manager_name
    calls:
        - [setContainer, [@service_container]]
```

Also, as a note, entity_manager_name is an optional parameter. I want the default for my particular use, so I just left it blank (just in case I ever rename the default manager).

Comment: I accidentally downvoted and now it won't let me fix it :/. Sorry about that. Can you make a small edit so I can upvote instead?

Comment: No worries. I was just concerned I had an error I needed to fix. =) I made a small tweak.

Comment: This actually has _something_ wrong. At least indentations are not good.

Answer (score 2):

**Since Symfony 3.3+ and 2017** you can make use of services.

Instead of other proposed solutions here that lead to:

- hacking the repository factory
- making service configuration in YAML
- and creating a lot of boilerplate code that will hunt you down later

You can do it...

## Clean Way - Dependency via Constructor Injection like in any other Service

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\Post;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

final class PostRepository
{
    /**
     * @var EntityRepository
     */
    private $repository;

    /**
     * @var YourOwnDependency
     */
    private $yourOwnDependency;

    public function __construct(YourOwnDependency $YourOwnDependency, EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->repository = $entityManager->getRepository(Post::class);

        $this->yourOwnDependency = $yourOwnDependency
    }
}
```

### Read More in the Post

You can read more detailed tutorial with clear code examples in [How to use Repository with Doctrine as Service in Symfony](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/10/16/how-to-use-repository-with-doctrine-as-service-in-symfony/) post.

Answer (score 1):

I've just define my own RepositoryFactory class

1. Create RepositoryFactory class and define service, for example `my_service.orm_repository.robo_repository_factory`, with include @service_container injection
2. And add check and set container service, for instance:

   ```
   private function createRepository(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, $entityName)
   {
       /* @var $metadata \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata */
       $metadata = $entityManager->getClassMetadata($entityName);
       $repositoryClassName = $metadata->customRepositoryClassName
           ?: $entityManager->getConfiguration()->getDefaultRepositoryClassName();

       $result = new $repositoryClassName($entityManager, $metadata);
       if ($result instanceof ContainerAwareInterface) {
           $result->setContainer($this->container);
       }
       return $result;
   }
   ```
3. Create compiler class

   ```
   public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
   {
       $def = $container->getDefinition('doctrine.orm.configuration');
       $def->addMethodCall(
           'setRepositoryFactory', [new Reference('robo_doctrine.orm_repository.robo_repository_factory')]
       );
   }
   ```
4. After that any `EntityRepository` with `ContainerAwareInterface` has @service_container

Answer (score -2):

You can actually create your own `DefaultRepository extends EntityRepository`, construct it with all dependencies you need and then set it as a default `Repository` with:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        entity_managers:
            default:
                default_repository_class: AppBundle\ORM\DefaultRepository
```