# Passing custom entity repositoriy classes to service via services.yml

Tags: dependency-injection, symfony, doctrine-orm

I try to load my service with custom repositories via services.yml

Now I have:

```
parameters:
    job_entity_name:  Marek\JobeetBundle\Entity\Job
    category_entity_name:  Marek\JobeetBundle\Entity\Category

services:
  job_metadata:
    class: Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetaData
    arguments: 
      name: [%job_entity_name%]
  category_metadata:
    class: Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetaData
    arguments: 
      name: [%category_entity_name%]
  job_repo:
    class: Marek\JobeetBundle\Repositories\JobRepository
    arguments: 
      em: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
      class: [@job_metadata] 
  category_repo:
    class: Marek\JobeetBundle\Repositories\CategoryRepository
    arguments: 
      em: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
      class: [@category_metadata]      
  job_service:
    class: Marek\JobeetBundle\JobService
    arguments:    
      jobRepo: [@job_repo]
      categoryRepo: [@category_repo]
```

Error:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   D:\Devel\symfony2\jobeet\vendor\doctrine\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata.php
>   line 66

I give up. Could somebody help?

**[EDIT]**

Of course my schema was bad, correct on is:

```
services:
  job_metadata:
    class: Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetaData
    arguments: 
      name: "Marek\JobeetBundle\Entity\Job"
  category_metadata:
    class: Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetaData
    arguments: 
      name: "Marek\JobeetBundle\Entity\Category"
  job_repo:
    class: Marek\JobeetBundle\Repositories\JobRepository
    arguments: 
      em: @doctrine.orm.entity_manager
      class: @job_metadata 
  category_repo:
    class: Marek\JobeetBundle\Repositories\CategoryRepository
    arguments: 
      em: @doctrine.orm.entity_manager
      class: @category_metadata      
  job_service:
    class: Marek\JobeetBundle\JobService
    arguments:    
      jobRepo: @job_repo
      categoryRepo: @category_repo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this answer you'll find a better way to define repositories as services (i.e. using factory-services and factory-methods).

[Injecting repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153103/injecting-dependency-into-entity-repository/8156241#8156241)