# Injecting @session into EntityRepository

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I wanted to override the default `Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository` class in my Symfony2 project so that I can have access to the `@session` service so that all of my repositories have access to a certain session variable if it is set.

On investigation it appeared to be less simple than I had hoped, as the EntityRepository is instantiated from within the `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager`, and this class is instantiated itself using a static "create" method.

I followed the answer in [Injecting dependency into entity repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153103/injecting-dependency-into-entity-repository) but have hit a roadblock in actually implementing the custom manager class (specifically where the answer's author says "But since you're making a custom entity manager, you can wire it up to the service container and inject whatever dependencies you need").

I have defined my overridden EntityManager class, with an overridden "create" function and have also overridden the "getRepository" function. It is in this function that I believe I need to add the session to the Repository as it is created using a "setSession" method on my overridden EntityRepository class, but I am unsure as to how to actually get the session into the manager in the first place, as the other constructor arguments for the EntityManager class (`Connection $conn, Configuration $config, EventManager $eventManager`) are supplied in the `Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DependencyInjection\DoctrineExtension` "ormLoad" method.

I have also specified

```
doctrine.orm.entity_manager.class: Me\MyBundle\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
```

in my config.yml file.

How can I have Symfony use my custom EntityManager class when creating repositories, and inject the session into it as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going with something slightly different:

I overrode the `doctrine.orm.entity_manager.class` parameter with my custom class which simple extended the default class with an additional `$session` parameter (complete with getter and setter), along with overridden `create` and `getRepository` functions (to return instances of my class instead of the default.

I then overrode the `EntityRepository` class and implemented a "getSession" method which returned

```
$this->_em->getSession();
```

and finally, in a custom event listener which has access to the entity manager, I called

```
$this->entityManager->setSession($session);
```

which gave me access to the session from every repository.

Answer (score 3):

Florian, **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17228417/symfony-2-creating-a-service-from-a-repository)**, explained how to create repository via service:

```
my_service:
    class: Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectRepository
    factory_service: doctrine # this is an instance of Registry
    factory_method: getRepository
    arguments: [ %mytest.entity% ]
```

You could add `calls` to invoke `setSession` (as deferred DI):

```
my_service:
    ...
    calls:
        - [setSession, ["@session"]]
```

Is this you're trying to do?

Comment: That's the sort of thing I want to do, but I need to make my custom EntityManager class the default EntityManager so I'm not sure how to go about telling Doctrine to use mine instead of theirs

Answer (score -1):

In Symfony 4+ you can just make it a `ServiceEntityRepository` and with autowiring there's no need for any **services.yaml** changes.

```
namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\YourEntity;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;

class YourRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    private $session;

    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry, SessionInterface $session)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
        parent::__construct($registry, YourEntity::class);
    }

    public function findSomethingUsingSession()
    {
        $someValue = $this->session->get('some_index');
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then in your controller (for example)

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(YourEntity::class);
$result = $repository->findSomethingUsingSession();
```

Or use dependency injection (recommended)

```
public function someAction(YourRepository $repository)
{
    $result = $repository->findSomethingUsingSession();
    // ...
}
```