# Inject additional configuration into custom Entity/Document Manager

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entitymanager

I made a custom Document Manager for my project implementing some new low level functions (following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8140007/1439070)).

Now I would like to inject a custom configuration in my new Document Manager (I suppose it would be the same with an Entity Manager). I have no idea of how to do this...

I want this config in my yaml files to set my custom Document Manager's parameters. The only way I found until now is to write a static function returning a hardcoded array of configuration, but it's a little dirty...)

Is there a proper way or an alternative to do this?

Answer (score 0):

For defining custom configuration in the *conig.yml* file, use [this symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html). You can access those configurations easily in a controller:

```
$this->container->getParameter(name_of_bundle_here)
```

Comment: Thanks @amcastror but the matter is I'm not in a controller or a simple service. I overwritten the DocumentManager with my custom one and I can't change injected dependencies. I just midified the DocumentManager class name, as explained in the post I linked in my question.