# How to Get Current User inside Repository Symfony 2.7

Tags: symfony, repository, entity, symfony-2.7

All of my query in Entity Repository needs to be filtered by user.

Now I want to know how can I access the currently logged in user in Entity Repository directly.

What I did today is to get the currently logged in user in my controller, through the use of **$this->getUser()** and then pass it to Entity Repository and this is not efficient.

Answer (score 8):

You need to inject `security.token_storage` service into another one to get the current user, but as of Repository classes belong to Doctrine project, not Symfony, it is not recommended to do this.. May be there is a way to achieve it by creating custom entityManager class as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153103/injecting-dependency-into-entity-repository), but I don't think it would a good solution..

Instead of customizing an `entityManager` better create a service which calls repository classes' methods, inject desired services into it.. Let Repository classes do their job.

Implementation would be something like this:

RepositoryClass:

```
class MyRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function fetchSomeDataByUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        // query
    } 
}
```

Service:

```
class MyService
{
    private $tokenStorage;

    public function _construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
        // other services
    }

    public function getSomeDataByUser()
    {
        $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();

        return $this->entityManager->getRepository(MyREPOSITORY)->fetchSomeDataByUser($user);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public function someAction()
{
    $dataByUser = $this->get(MYSERVICE)->getSomeDataByUser();
}
```

Comment: this is the best way to do it

Answer (score 2):

If you use [JMSDiExtraBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSDiExtraBundle) it can be done by adding setter injection:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation as DI;

class YourRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    /** @var User current user entity */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * @DI\InjectParams({
     *      "token_storage" = @DI\Inject("security.token_storage")
     * })
     */
    public function setSimplaManager(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        $token = $tokenStorage->getToken();
        if (!is_object($user = $token->getUser())) {
            // e.g. anonymous authentication
            return;
        }

        $this->user = $user;
    }
}
```