# ParamConverter: inject curent user in Repository

Tags: symfony

In a view, I want to display linked values, but all of the linked values can't be displayed because they depends to the user access.

To do that I just need to do a leftJoin with a ->where('user', $user). The question is... how can I inject the current user in the Repository from the ParamConverter ?

Comment: Is your user access done using the symfony role system?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8153103/1220930

Comment: Yes, he can access to the view, but in the view, I list other objects, and I want list only objects he can acces. To do it, I need to do a query where I specify the current User to filter results.

Comment: I think you will need your own custom converter: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html  Might be easier to just skip the converter and do what @Roonetly suggests in his answer.

Comment: Yes I think... I need to check the is_granted too, but, it's the easiest way... For the moment, I use a is_granted in the view on each loop, and do a big request to avoid sub doctrine request. But it's not optimal...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Doctrine, this should work;

In your controller;

```
$objRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AppBundle:Objects');

$files = $this->objRepo->getAllForUserId($this->getUser()->getId());
```

And in your repo file;

```
public function getAllForUserId($user_id, $limit=100)
{
    if (null === $user_id) {
        throw new ORMInvalidArgumentException('User id not set');
    }

    $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('obj');

    $queryBuilder->select(array('obj', 'usr'))
        ->innerJoin('obj.users', 'usr')
        ->where('usr.id = :user_id')
        ->setParameter(':user_id', $user_id)
        ->orderBy('file.created', Criteria::DESC);

    $query = $queryBuilder->getQuery();

    return $query->getResult();

}
```