# How to override/extend default Doctrine EntityManager class in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, extend, entitymanager

I've created some additional methods to help with managing entities in a Symfony2 project.  I would like these method to be available on Doctrine's EntityManager which is obtained from the container with the "doctrine.orm.entity_manager" key.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138962/is-there-a-way-to-specify-doctrine2-entitymanager-implementation-class-in-symfon), and tried implementing it, but it is not working.  I get an error that says `The attribute "name" must be set for path "doctrine.orm.entity_managers".`

This is an older post, so it may be some kind of "trick" that has been deprecated since then; I'm using the latest stable versions of Symfony2 and Doctrine.

Is there a way to override the class that Doctrine uses to create it's default EntityManager, or am I going to have to just create like another service and use that instead?

Comment: For what matter would you do this?

Comment: I've just added some helper methods, like for dealing with larger groups of entities to persist.  For instance, I have a method that takes multiple entities, persists them, and then runs a flush at the end of the operation.  They're not big changes, but small things that will save me time as I start building other things.

Comment: Why don't you create another class taking the `EntityManager` as constructor parameter and will deal with the methods you need instead?

Comment: That is possible, but it would be most convenient to just override, really extend, whatever class Doctrine uses.  That way somebody can just get the "doctrine.orm.entity_manager" service and have access to these additional methods, rather than having to use another class or service to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Way remains the same.

Override parameter `doctrine.orm.entity_manager.class` from [orm.xml](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/orm.xml#L9) in your services.yml with your custom EntityManager class that extends [Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php).

Override [create](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php#L916) method(it changed a little bit)

```
public static function create($conn, Configuration $config, EventManager $eventManager = null)
{
    if ( ! $config->getMetadataDriverImpl()) {
        throw ORMException::missingMappingDriverImpl();
    }

    switch (true) {
        case (is_array($conn)):
            $conn = \Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getConnection(
                $conn, $config, ($eventManager ?: new EventManager())
            );
            break;

        case ($conn instanceof Connection):
            if ($eventManager !== null && $conn->getEventManager() !== $eventManager) {
                 throw ORMException::mismatchedEventManager();
            }
            break;

        default:
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Invalid argument: " . $conn);
    }

    // return your instance of em
    return new MyEntityManager($conn, $config, $conn->getEventManager());
}
```

Error that you see is the fact that you have the wrong settings in the config.yml for doctrine. See [reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html).

Comment: I'm not seeing any reference to the "doctrine.orm.entity_manager.class" config item in the page.  I notice that the example is showing multiple entity manager definitions, but I am not seeing a "class" setting under them either.

Comment: Its just a string in parameters, see [orm.xml](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/orm.xml#L9)

Comment: see this link : http://forum.symfony-project.org/forum/23/topic/36727.html