# ZF2 Override EntityManager & Doctrine entity namespace aliases

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

How to override EntityManager in ZF2

```
MyEntityManager extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager {

}
```

So after using

`$this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager')`

or

`$this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default')`

I will get MyEntityManager.

**Edit**
In comments I also asked about How to create aliases (shortcuts) for entity namespaces.

```
getRepository('Application\Entity\Some\Very\Nested\MyEntity')
getRepository('NestedShortcut:MyEntity')
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve that makes you want to redefine the `entityManager`?

Comment: Yesss! I would be more then surprised if I would get answer without that question :) But I understand this protection named "Lets check if this guy isn't another n00b that see D2 for the first time" :D
I did that in my other non zend project to achieve a lot of small improvements. For example I make getRepository function to use global (defined in config) aliases so there is no need to specify whole namespace to each entity.

Comment: You can use `addEntityNamespace` for that. Seems more the right way. But if you really want to do that check the linked answer below.

Comment: I have namespace defined `'doctrine' => array(
  'driver' => array(
   __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => array(
    'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
    'cache' => 'array',
    'paths' => array(
     __DIR__ . '/../src/Application/Entity',
    )
   ),
   'orm_default' => array(
    'drivers' => array(
     'Application\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver',
    )
   )
  )
 )` and to get some nested entity I must do `getRepository('Application\Entity\Some\Very\Nested\Entity')`
How to add alias so I can do `getRepository('MyNested\Entity')`?

Comment: Check the edited answer. Maybe it would be nice to past the code from your comment into your question for readability and it might be nice for others who want to do the same... Good luck with it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Check this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8140007/1697459) That is what you want right?

### EDIT:

To answer your namespace question:

```
$config = $entityManager->getConfiguration();
$config->addEntityNamespace('MyNested', 'Application\Entity\Some\Very\Nested');
$myNestedEntity = $entityManager->getRepository('MyNested:Entity');
```

Beware of the semicolon `:` instead of the slash `\`

Comment: Both answers are correct for me. Now I can do shortcuts in more proper way AND override EM to my needs. More then good answer!