# Symfony 4 doctrine, override an existing method

Tags: oop, php-7, symfony4

From doctrine vendor in Symfony4, the 'persist' method takes one entity in parameter. I would like create my own apersist function which takes an array of entity in parameter, how can I override the EntityManager->persist method from a custom class by a new method 'apersist' like this ?

```
class MyEm extends EntityManager 
{
  public function apersist($entities){
    foreach($entities as $entity){
      // ?? (I tried with '$this->persist($entity)' or 'parent::persist($entity)' but I get errors) 
    }
}
```

And from a class controller :

```
public function create(MyEm $mem){ // I get errors when I try use my MyEm class from create parameter
  $entities[] = new foo();
  $entities[] = new foo();
  $mem->apersist($entities);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to specify Doctrine2 Entitymanager implementation class in Symfony2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138962/is-there-a-way-to-specify-doctrine2-entitymanager-implementation-class-in-symfon)

Comment: PS: don't follow the marked answer (_its obsolete and shows a wrong way to do it_) and take a look at [How to Decorate Services](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_decoration.html).